# searched values to show as msgbox from datagridview in VB.net

Tags: search, datagridview, msgbox

I am viewing my data through datagridview from comma delimited *text file. I search and found the values and changing its color and font for separating. Actually this is enough. But I am planning to show the column(1) values of the searched rows through msgbox and later to speech synthesis for for giving information to others.
My issue is, I couldn't display the searched values in column(1) in msgbox. My search criteria is time. In my column(1), I have some text, and it is to be searched by time and display as msgbox. All in one msgbox.
My program as is follows. It is working fine.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As     System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label4.Text = Format(Date.Now(), "HH:mm:ss")
    tt = Format(Date.Now(), "HH:mm:ss")
    For i As Integer = 0 To DGV1.RowCount - 1
        If DGV1.Rows(i).Cells("Column3").Value.ToString = tt Then
            DGV1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
            DGV1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("TAHOMA", 14, FontStyle.Bold)
            MsgBox(DGV1.Rows(i).Cells("Column0").Value.ToString)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Two three days I am with this..... Thanking you ....

Comment: In column(3) having different time to show to follow up....

Answer (score 0):

I found it...
First change the property of datagridview to "Full Row select" in selection mode. Then change the msgbox command to
"Msgbox(DGV1.Selectedrow(i).Cells(" Column0"). Value.To string) and placed to outside of the if then conditional statement.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick  
Label4.Text = Format(Date.Now(), "HH:mm:ss") 
tt = Format(Date.Now(), "HH:mm:ss") 
For i As Integer = 0 To DGV1.RowCount - 1 
If DGV1.Rows(i).Cells("Column3").Value.ToString = tt Then 
DGV1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
DGV1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("TAHOMA", 14, FontStyle.Bold)
End If
MsgBox(DGV1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("Column0").Value.ToString)
Next i
End Sub
```

My next issue is " two more selected data not coming in one msgbox... Please help me to resolve this issue..